# Replacing class name BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse an HTML document, and was wondering if you guys can help me out.

```
<tr height="21" style="height:15.75pt">
       <td class="style14" height="21" style="height: 15.75pt">
        71
       </td>
       <td class="style14">
        Breakeven
       </td>
       <td class="style10">
        The Script
        <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">
        </span>
       </td>
      </tr>
```

I would like to change td class= 'style10' to class='style14'. However, when I change it to style14, it does not pick it up. So, "The Script" doesn't get printed.

Here's my code:

```
search =soup.find('td', class_='style10')
search['class'] = 'style14'

for each in search: 
    print each.text
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What can't you modify the class *after* iterating over the `search`?

Comment: what do you get if you just print each in your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over **one element**, and that only lists child elements. Because your selected tag has no child elements with further text (the `<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">` element is empty), you don't see anything.

Just don't loop, get to the text directly:

```
print search.text
```

Your class change didn't break anything here.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <tr height="21" style="height:15.75pt">
...        <td class="style14" height="21" style="height: 15.75pt">
...         71
...        </td>
...        <td class="style14">
...         Breakeven
...        </td>
...        <td class="style10">
...         The Script
...         <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">
...         </span>
...        </td>
...       </tr>
... ''')
>>> search =soup.find('td', class_='style10')
>>> search['class']
['style10']
>>> search['class'] = 'style14'
>>> search['class']
'style14'
>>> list(search)
[u'\n        The Script\n        ', <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">
</span>, u'\n']
>>> search.text
u'\n        The Script\n        \n\n'
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know I was looping something that was empty. It's fixed now.