# Replace css classes in place using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I am parsing an html document and want to retrieve all css blockquote tags of class "FlatParagraph", however, there are some classes that include another class that I would like to exclude "FlatParagraph view-history-note". My thoughts are to replace the class "FlatParagraph view-history-note" with class "view-history-note".

My question is similar to this one (if the best method is to replace the unwanted class) ([Replacing class name BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452492/replacing-class-name-beautifulsoup)), however, I need the updated classes to remain in place in the original code as I have further querying to do and I need a find_all() approach rather than find() as there is more than one class "FlatParagraph view-history-note" to replace. I thought maybe regex, but was having issues with converting string back to html for further querying.

I'd really appreciate any help, thanks.

Here's an example of the format. I want to exclude the `<BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph view-history-note">` lines.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <div>I don't want this tag</div>
        <p>I have already been extracted</p>
        <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>
            <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph view-history-note">I don't want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>
            <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph view-history-note">I don't want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>
            <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph view-history-note">I don't want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>
        <p>I have already been extracted</p>
        <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>
        <p>I have already been extracted</p>
        <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>
        <p>I have already been extracted</p>
        <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>
            <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph view-history-note">I don't want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>
    </head>
</html>
```

I have tried `soup.select(".FlatParagraph")` but this retrieves the `.FlatParagraph view-history-note` blockquotes as well.

I have also tried getting all children from the parent, only the first 10 or so children are returned (the html is over 1000 lines long).

Expected results for the html above would be

```
[<BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>, <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>, <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>, <BLOCKQUOTE class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</BLOCKQUOTE>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

```
# using CSS selector
r = soup.select('blockquote[class="FlatParagraph"]')

# using lambda
r = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'blockquote' and tag.get('class') == ['FlatParagraph'])
```

(taken from [BeautifulSoup - How to find a specific class name alone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123550/1248974)
)

both will exclude results without the undesired tags:

```
[<blockquote class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</blockquote>, <blockquote class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</blockquote>, <blockquote class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</blockquote>, <blockquote class="FlatParagraph">I want to keep this part</blockquote>]
```

however the result will contain lowercased tags since [all tags are lowercased as per the HTML specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21562001/1248974) so "If you want to preserve mixed-case or uppercase tags and attributes, you’ll need to [parse the document as XML](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml)."

Comment: As a point of note, a class name being "alone" is not the same as an element not containing a certain combination of classes. If `FlatParagraph` at any point has other classes (that aren't `view-history-notes`) that shouldn't be excluded from the query then they'll be left out.

Answer (score 0):

If BeautifulSoup allows all CSS selectors then `soup.select(".FlatParagraph:not(.view-history-note)")` should work by excluding elements with the `FlatPragraph` class that also have the `view-history-note` class.

For more reading on the `:not()` pseudo selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this and it returned len = 0. Thanks for the material, I will read up on this.